# How to export oracle database version 12.1.0.2.0 with expdp Release 12.2.0.1.0

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, expdp

I am running following command to dump my database

```
./expdp username/password@//host:port/database directory=/home/ubuntu/oracle/instantclient_12_2 dumpfile=dumpfilename.dmp content=METADATA_ONLY
```

and getting following error

```
Export: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Fri Sep 14 06:14:28 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
UDE-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 12.1.0.2.0
```

I tried searching and there were suggestion to use `VERSION` parameter which I did still no success.

Does anyone have idea what should i do to overcome the issue?

I cant use `instantclient-tools-macos.x32-12.1.0.2.0.zip` as it doesnt have `expdp` command.

Comment: Which VERSION value did you use? Should be 12.1, right?

Comment: @Littlefoot i tried `compatible`, `12.1`, `12.2` almost evertthing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATA PUMP PL/SQL API[Examples of Using the Data Pump API Oracle Doc 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/using-oracle_datapump-api.html#GUID-5AAC848B-5A2B-4FD1-97ED-D3A048263118)